# Add bar between directories with sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed

I'm using the [`tree`](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/tree.1.html) utility to recursively show directories like this:

```
$ tree -F -a --dirsfirst project
project
├── my_app/
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests/
    ├── integration/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_integration.py
    └── unit/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_sum.py

$ tree -F -a --dirsfirst helloworld
helloworld
├── helloworld/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   └── helpers.py
├── tests/
│   ├── helloworld_tests.py
│   └── helpers_tests.py
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

I'd like to pipe this into `sed` or `awk` to make a slight change: **at the end of any directory's listing**, a newline + literal `|` gets inserted:

```
project/
├── my_app/
│   └── __init__.py
│
└── tests/
    ├── integration/
    |   ├── __init__.py
    |   └── test_integration.py
    |
    └── unit/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_sum.py

helloworld/
├── helloworld/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   └── helpers.py
│
├── tests/
│   ├── helloworld_tests.py
│   └── helpers_tests.py
│
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

How can I make this replacement?

---

Current attempt & logic: newline + `|` gets inserted after a leading `│` and before a leading `├──` (optional whitespace before both of these):

```
tree -F -a --dirsfirst helloworld | sed -E 's/^\s*\│.*\n\s*\├──/???/g'
```

Stuck horribly there -- 100 times more proficient in Python's `re` and some `grep` than sed/awk.

Comment: Would a solution using perl be acceptable?

Comment: Surely, would be interested to see that @melpomene.  I may post a Python solution as well since both are widely available.

Comment: Are those `└` and `├` characters in your example literally present in the `tree` output or are they some kind of copy/past snafu representing `|-`?

Comment: They are present literally as `│` and `├──` @EdMorton.  (Copied directly from Bash shell stdout -- see http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)

Comment: I've simplified my solution and converted it to bona fide sed. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using Perl:

```
perl -pe 'if (/│.*└/) { print; s/ *└.*// }'
```

Idea:
For every line containing `│` and `└` somewhere afterwards, trim `└` and all following characters and all preceding spaces, then output that modified line.

Effect:

```
│    │   └── foo.xyz
```

will be followed by a new line containing just

```
│    │
```

in the output.

Sed version:

```
sed '/│.*└/{p;s/ *└.*//}'
```

For your sample input it produces the following output:

```
$ tree -F -a --dirsfirst project
project
├── my_app/
│   └── __init__.py
│
└── tests/
    ├── integration/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_integration.py
    │
    └── unit/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_sum.py

$ tree -F -a --dirsfirst helloworld
helloworld
├── helloworld/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   └── helpers.py
│
├── tests/
│   ├── helloworld_tests.py
│   └── helpers_tests.py
│
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cat file` in place of the 2 tree commands in your question with GNU awk:

```
$ cat file | awk '1; match($0,/^((\s*│)+)\s+└/,a){ print a[1] }'
project
├── my_app/
│   └── __init__.py
│
└── tests/
    ├── integration/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_integration.py
    │
    └── unit/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_sum.py

helloworld
├── helloworld/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   └── helpers.py
│
├── tests/
│   ├── helloworld_tests.py
│   └── helpers_tests.py
│
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

and with any awk:

```
$ cat file | awk '1; match($0,/^[[:space:]]*(│[[:space:]]+)+└/){ print substr($0,1,RLENGTH-1) }'
```

and with GNU sed:

```
$ cat file | sed -En 'p; s/^((\s*│)+)\s+└.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*│\)\s*└──.*/&\n\1/' file
```

Where file could be stdin from a pipe of the tree command e.g.

```
tree -Fa --dirsfirst helloworld | sed 's/\(.*│\)\s*└──.*/&\n\1/'
```